# objectpath json query to get array values in python

Tags: python, json, objectpath

I've got some JSON like the following:

```
{
"books": [
    {
        "name": "Matthew"
    },
    {
        "name": "Mark",
        "sections": [
            {
                "reference": "1:1-1:8",
                "tags": [
                    "a",
                    "b"
                ],
                "summary": "blah",
                "notes": ""
            },
            {
                "reference": "1:9-1:15",
                "tags": [
                    "b",
                    "c",
                    "d"
                ],
                "summary": "",
                "notes": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I want to get a list of all sections using objectpath.

I've tried:

```
sections = Tree(db).execute('$.books[@.name is "Mark"].sections')
for section in sections:
    print(section)
    print("----\n")
```

but what is returned is a single section, which is an array. That is sections only has a single result while I am expecting (or at least wanting) just the array of 'sections'.
This would save me having a for loop in a for loop.

Is there some special syntax to make it return how I want?

I've also tried:

```
'$.books[@.name is "Mark"].sections.*'
'$.books[@.name is "Mark"].sections[*]'
```

with no luck.

Comment: What's wrong with the python `json` library? `[book['sections'] for book in json.loads(json_obj)['books']]`

Comment: I"m using objectpath to help divorce the data structure from the code, so want to keep just a few strings in objectcode makes changing data layout very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*sections* is a generator object. To get the first item from it you can use `next()` function:

```
sections = Tree(db).execute('$.books[@.name is "Mark"].sections')
print(sections) # will show that it's a generator
for section in next(sections):
    print(section)
    print("----\n")
```

This first item will be the list with individual sections. Now you can iterate over each section using for loop.

Comment: This example helped me to extract a value from a nested json perfectly. Thanks